# How to get Method Name of Generic Func<T> passed into Method

Tags: c#, generics, func

I'm trying to get the method name of a function passed into an object using a .Net closure like this:

Method Signature

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(Func<IEnumerable<T>> WebServiceCallback) 
where T : class    
{
    // either gets me '<LoadData>b__3'
    var a = nrdsWebServiceCallback.Method.Name;
    var b = nrdsWebServiceCallback.GetInvocationList();

    return WebServiceCallback();
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
SessionStateService.Labs = CacheManager.GetData(() =>  
WCFService.GetLabs(SessionStateService.var1, SessionStateService.var2));
```

Seeing 'b__3' instead of WCFServce.GetLabs(..) etc

Comment: Reading up on this would help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx
It is possible to get the name from parsing the expression tree though, but why do you need this?

Comment: You get `<LoadData>b__3` because that's the name of the compiler-generated function. Your delegate knows nothing of `WCFService.GetLabs`, that's contained entirely within `<LoadData>b__3`.

Comment: Why do you need this? For logging.

Answer (score 22):

You're looking at the name of the lambda expression (generated by the compiler), instead of the name of the method called inside the lambda.

You have to use an `<Expression<Func<T>>` instead of a `Func<T>`. Expressions can be parsed and analyzed.

Try

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(Expression<Func<IEnumerable<T>>> callbackExpression) 
where T : class    
{
    var methodCall = callbackExpression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if(methodCall != null)
    {
        string methodName = methodCall.Method.Name;
    }

    return callbackExpression.Compile()();
}
```

Comment: `return WebServiceCallback();` won't compile like this, because you removed `WebServiceCallback`.

Comment: @hvd Thanks, i didn't notice that. Just fixed it.

Comment: Looks good to me now as an answer to the question as asked. I have my doubts about the underlying problem that makes the OP want to analyse the function, though, but given the limited information included in the question there's not much that can be said about that.

Comment: @hvd Me too - expression analysis is only required to solve a few very specific problems. Maybe he's just exploring the language?

Comment: I'm wrapping a series of existing WS calls in a Cache Manager. It must decide whether to use the existing WS call (slower) or use the local DB cache (speed improvement). I need a way of linking the specific DB Cache table with each method (each has a different cache table). My first though was I could use the method name to do this. I could of course pass it in as a string parm and do the same.

Comment: @BarryMcDermid Depending on how your service is structured, making it depend on `typeof(T)` could be enough. If multiple services do return the same type, my personal preference would be to write it as `SessionStateService.Labs = CacheManager.GetData(WCFService.GetLabs, SessionStateService.var1, SessionStateService.var2);` where the first parameter is a delegate (not an expression tree).

Comment: @hvd Good suggestion. Considered that. The services all use IEnumerable<..> for return types but the specific type they return varies thus using IEnumerable<T> for the return type.

Comment: Does this approach have some performance issue or something to take care?

Answer (score 2):

What is actually passed into your function is an anonymous lambda function (`() => WCFService.Etc`), so what you're seeing is the actual method name - `<LoadData>b__3` is the autogenerated name for the anonymous method.

What you actually want is the method called *inside* the method called. For that, you need to delve into expressions. Instead of `Func<IEnumerable<T>>`, define your parameter as `Expression<Func<IEnumerable<T>>>`, and call this code:

```
var body = nrdsWebServiceCallback.Body as MethodCallExpression;
if (body != null)
   Console.WriteLine(body.Method.DeclaringType.Name + "." + body.Method.Name);
```